# Magento's addAttributeToFilter not working

Tags: magento

First of all, I'm completely new in Magento, so I have little knowledge in its structure and functioning.

I'm building a custom module for filtering and displaying products.
So far i am doing ok, but now I'm struggling to filter and display the products hehe.

I have created a catalog block in `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Filter.php`
Source:

```
<?php
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Filter extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{      
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $table = Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix() . 'custom_table';

        //GET
        $param1 = $this->getRequest()->getParam('param1');
        $param2 = $this->getRequest()->getParam('param1');
        $param3 = $this->getRequest()->getParam('param3');
        $param4 = $this->getRequest()->getParam('param4');

        $sql = "SELECT sku FROM " . $table . " WHERE param1 = '".$param1."' AND param2 = '".$param2."' AND param3 = '".$param3."' AND param4 = '".$param4."'";
        $query = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
        ->getConnection('core_read')
        ->fetchAll( $sql );

        $res = $query[0];//only one result expected

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => $res['sku']))
            ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
            ->setCurPage(1)
        ;

        $this->setProductCollection($collection);
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

}
?>
```

And my module uses a .phtml.
Source:

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_filter')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')->toHtml();
```

The problem is:
It's suposed to load only the product with the SKU retrieved from database. But, instead, it always loads the same product, no matter what I put in addAttributeToFilter.

For testing purposes, I deleted all the content from Filter.php (except the class declaration) and the behavior was the same. I also hardcoded a sku in addAttributeToFilter, no luck.
I checked the query and the result, and it is correct.

Other approaches i've tried:

```
$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter( 'sku', array( 'in' => array( $res['sku'] ) ) );
        $this->setProductCollection($_testproductCollection);
```

/*-------------------------*/

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => $idsProdutos));
$this->setProductCollection($collection);
```

/*-------------------------*/

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'asd');//show only skus starting with... 
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//enabled
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);//catalog, search
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $products->load();
        $this->setProductCollection($products);
```

Any help is very appreciated.

**EDIT**

Found the solution!

At the end of the script (before the `return`), I've included this line:

```
$this->_productCollection = $collection;
```

and for some reason, now it is working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `addAttributeToFilter` is used with EAV attributes only. SKU is store as a normal column in product's table. You could try use `addFieldToFilter`. Although, if you are looking for only one product, you should follow dagfr answer.

Comment: Tried using addFieldToFilter, but it still isn't working. For some reason, the collection is not being properly set (?).
As I said to dagfr, I can have up to 3 sku returned, so I'll need the collection.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have 1 Sku returned, do not use a collection, just use the product :

```
$product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct('SKU_GOES_HERE', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(), 'sku');
```

If you really need a collection you can the filter by entity_id with the `$product->getId()`

Comment: Actually I'll have up to 3 sku returned. That is why I'm using collections and filtering using 'in'.

Comment: I tried this, but the same product is always returned, don't matter what I put in the collection.